# Solving a PDE by wavelets

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, wavelets

I know how to solve a PDE by wavelets. I found a lot of articles about it.

**But,** if the PDE includes Dirac Delta distribution $( \delta)$, how to solve it by wavelets? (Haar, Legendre, Chebyshev wavelets don' t matter) I haven' t found any articles or books about it.

**For example:**
 $$\begin{aligned}  \frac{\partial^{2} y}{\partial t^{2}}=\delta(x-v t) +\frac{\partial^{2} y}{\partial x^{2}} v^{2} \delta(x-v t) \end{aligned}$$
with Appropriate Initial and boundary conditions. (in here $v$ is a real number)

***Could you give me some hints or suggest some articles which include PDE with Dirac Delta distribution?***

Comment: Do you want to analytically or numerically solve the PDE?

Comment: numerically by wavelet method (Haar, Legendre, Chebyshev wavelets don' t matter)

Comment: What you could do is recast the PDE in its weak form (in space) and then discretize the spaces of test and trial functions with wavelets and then compute the integrals and other various quantities numerically. It will lead you to a set of ODE in time you could solve as well. I am not sure what happens with your $\delta$ distributions though.

Answer (score 0):

Possible recipe for numerical work:

- Generic form of the PDE $$\partial_t^2y-a(x,t)\partial_x^2y=b(x,t)$$
- Weak form in space (you could extend to space-time if needed) with trial function $y$ and test function $v$ $$\forall v(x),\quad \int v (\partial_t^2y-a(x,t)\partial_x^2y-b(x,t))\,\mathrm{d}\Omega=0$$ that is [loose integration by parts but you do not specify the domain of interest and Boundary conditions, if any] $$\forall v,\quad \int v\,\partial_t^2y+A(x,t)\partial_xv\,\partial_xy\,\mathrm{d}\Omega=\int v\, b\,\mathrm{d}\Omega$$ (I am not sure about the expression of $A$ above)
- Wavelet discretization $$v(x)=\sum_i a_i \phi_i(x)\quad\text{and}\quad y(x,t)=\sum_i b_i(t)\psi_i(x)$$ where the $\phi_i$ and $\psi_i$ families are wavelets of your choice.
- Numerically compute the above integrals (note that since there are $\delta$ in the above integrals, the latter should be read in the sense of distributions, ie $\int \delta_a f =f(a)$) and solve in $b_i(t)$